# How to change text in specified time blocks in Javascript using setTimeOut?

Tags: javascript

I have made a Javascript code which first assesses the current time of the local machine and displays text/message according to time blocks specified. For example, the message will be "Notification-1" between time block 00 Hrs - 04 Hrs. Thus there are 6 time blocks in 24 hours (eg 00 Hrs to 04 Hrs, 04 Hrs to 08 Hrs..... 20 Hrs to 00 Hrs ).

My code is working well if the new browser is opened, but it will not change the text automatically until the browser is refreshed.

**My question is:** I need that text/message should rotate automatically without page refresh according to the time blocks specified.

I know PHP but noob in Javascript and don't know how to use setTimeOut. Secondly, if it will be a infinite loop or recursive, will it consume the machine resources excessively?

My working Code is:

```
    <p id="try"></p>

    <script>
    var d = new Date();
    var curr_hour = d.getHours();
    var curr_minute = d.getMinutes();
    var curr_time = curr_hour + curr_minute/60;


    if (curr_time >= 0 && curr_time < 4) {
       document.getElementById("try").innerHTML = "Notification-1";

    } else if (curr_time >= 4 && curr_time < 8) {
       document.getElementById("try").innerHTML = "Notification-2";

    } else if (curr_time >= 8 && curr_time < 12) {
       document.getElementById("try").innerHTML = "Notification-3";

    } else if (curr_time >= 12 && curr_time < 16) {
       document.getElementById("try").innerHTML = "Notification-4";

    } else if (curr_time >= 16 && curr_time < 20 ) {
       document.getElementById("try").innerHTML = "Notification-5";

    } else if (curr_time >= 20 && curr_time < 23.98 ) {
       document.getElementById("try").innerHTML = "Notification-6";

    } 

</script>
```

I got the below code that said to replace the function of SetInterval at every second but not capable enough to apply:

```
// A basic setTimeout loop, mimicking setInterval
var doStuff = function () {
  // Do stuff
   setTimeout(doStuff, 1000);
};
setTimeout(doStuff, 1000);
```

Comment: The solution is your second code block. What's your issue with it? You just need to copy your current code where the `// Do stuff` comment is

Comment: Just put all of your code in a function and call it with an interval `setInterval(function() { //your function }, 60000);` and it will update every minute (in this case).

Comment: What was wrong with using `setInterval`? I can't see if you say anywhere in your question why you aren't using it, given that it's exactly what you need and would avoid the recursive call to `setTimeout`, and you say that the function is meant to mimic `setInterval` anyway...

Comment: @IStanlay, I gone through this  [link]http://reallifejs.com/brainchunks/repeated-events-timeout-or-interval/[link] while deciding between `setInterval` or `setTimeout` just an attempt to write good code. No issue with `setInterval`.

Answer (score 2):

I'd use setInterval instead.
For such a simple script, you won't have any resource usage problem.

```
<p id="try"></p>

<script>
function showNotification() {
    var d = new Date();
    var curr_hour = d.getHours();
    var curr_minute = d.getMinutes();
    var curr_time = curr_hour + curr_minute/60;


    if (curr_time >= 0 && curr_time < 4) {
       document.getElementById("try").innerHTML = "Notification-1";

    } else if (curr_time >= 4 && curr_time < 8) {
       document.getElementById("try").innerHTML = "Notification-2";

    } else if (curr_time >= 8 && curr_time < 12) {
       document.getElementById("try").innerHTML = "Notification-3";

    } else if (curr_time >= 12 && curr_time < 16) {
       document.getElementById("try").innerHTML = "Notification-4";

    } else if (curr_time >= 16 && curr_time < 20 ) {
       document.getElementById("try").innerHTML = "Notification-5";

    } else if (curr_time >= 20 && curr_time < 23.98 ) {
       document.getElementById("try").innerHTML = "Notification-6";

    } 
}

setInterval(showNotification, 1000);

</script>
```

If you don't want to wait 1sec before the first message, just add showNotification(); after setInterval

Comment: this is preferred. or with setTimeout you can use var nametimeout = setTimeout(blah); then clear and null in the function so that it doesnt retain resources. but setInterval does just that by default.

Comment: @Francesco.D'Alesio your solution is awesome too.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should do it, you just wrap the code in a function so you can call it each timout period:

```
 <p id="try"></p>

    <script>
 function setTextNotification() {
    var d = new Date();
    var curr_hour = d.getHours();
    var curr_minute = d.getMinutes();
    var curr_time = curr_hour + curr_minute/60;

    if (curr_time >= 0 && curr_time < 4) {
       document.getElementById("try").innerHTML = "Notification-1";

    } else if (curr_time >= 4 && curr_time < 8) {
       document.getElementById("try").innerHTML = "Notification-2";

    } else if (curr_time >= 8 && curr_time < 12) {
       document.getElementById("try").innerHTML = "Notification-3";

    } else if (curr_time >= 12 && curr_time < 16) {
       document.getElementById("try").innerHTML = "Notification-4";

    } else if (curr_time >= 16 && curr_time < 20 ) {
       document.getElementById("try").innerHTML = "Notification-5";

    } else if (curr_time >= 20 && curr_time < 23.98 ) {
       document.getElementById("try").innerHTML = "Notification-6";

    } 
}
var doStuff = function () {
  setTextNotification();
   setTimeout(doStuff, 1000);
};
setTimeout(doStuff, 1000);  

</script>
```

Comment: You need to put the `d`, `curr_hour` etc variable definition inside the function otherwise the value will never update.

Comment: @Dr.AaronDishno you are too quick to response. You solution is working.